# Why does xterm/bash word-wrap even tho window is large to fit command

Tags: bash, xterm

So this happens some times, not always.
I'll write a really long command and I'll be satisfied with it wrapping around at the edge like so:

[image]

What I don't like to happen however is, after increasing the size of the window, if i write a new long command or go back in my command-history to my previously long command it will word-wrap in a way that destroys readablity, like so:

http://youtu.be/XnbmdqWzxyU

ArchLinux Linux kernel: 3.17.6-1
xterm version: 314-1
bash version: 4.3.030-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a [readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) thing. Add

```
set horizontal-scroll-mode on
```

to your readline configuration (usually `~/.inputrc`) and restart the shell or re-read the configuration (usually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

If not, then you are out of luck, I'm afraid - the terminal is usually meant to do exactly that, i.e. once the data gets too big, if wraps and gets displayed on a new line.

Comment: This might do it, will investigate further! :)

Comment: Sorry for getting back late to you peterph, took a while before this popped up again. It did the trick for sure. Thank you! :)

Comment: Works for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me most often when I resize while running a full-screen program that makes use of the [alternate screen](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/AlternateScreenPlague), such as `vim` or `less`. You can tell if this is the case if your scrollback buffer seems to disappear when you run the program, and then reappears when you exit.

When resizing while running such a program, the alternate screen is updated with the new terminal dimensions, but the underlying main screen is not. When you exit from the program and return to the command prompt on the main screen, the terminal's idea of its width is not the same as the xterm's. This is most evident if the xterm is widened, but it also causes subtle problems if it's made more narrow.

All that said, I was unable to duplicate this with xterm-271 on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. However, I see it all the time using mintty with Cygwin, and I suspect the fix is the same. Just change the width of your terminal, even if just by one character. Doing that reliably corrects the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

The cause may be that there is a margin set. This can occur if some curses application has not been terminated properly. In such a case, typing `reset` will reset the terminal, in particular the margin.

Comment: I did write reset in the video. Didn't work.